# How to create a sub-class instance from exception caught in super-class?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

1. A packet object is created by passing data to the super-class `SKBusPacket`.
2. The packet's sub-type is determined in the `__init__()` and an exception is raised according to what sub-type this packet is (a "request" or "response" sub-type).
3. This exception is caught and the data is instead passed to sub-classes `SKBusRequestPacket` or `SKBusResponsePacket`.

**Problem:** Creating an instance of the sub-classes will raise the aforementioned exceptions again and again because I pass the initialisation args to the super-class through `super` (see code).

**Proposed solution:** Avoid the `raise` by checking if the instance is one of the sub-classes, using `isinstance()`. But I'm under the impression that this is bad practice and un-pythonic.

My simplified code:

```
class SKBusPacket(Packet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SKBusPacket, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.packet_type = self.getSkbPacketType()

        if self.packet_type == 'request':
            raise ActuallySKBusReqPacket
        elif self.packet_type == 'response':
            raise ActuallySKBusPRPacket

    # Here go some attributes and methods common to all packets...

# Both Request and Response packets inherit from base-class "SKBusPacket"
class SKBusRequestPacket
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Pass init arguments to super-class "SKBusPacket".
        super(SKBusRequestPacket, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class SKBusResponsePacket
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Pass init arguments to super-class "SKBusPacket".
        super(SKBusResponsePacket, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


def log_skbus(raw_pkt):
    try:
        pkt = SKBusPacket(raw_pkt.data)
    except ActuallyRequestPacket:
        pkt = SKBusRequestPacket(raw_pkt.data)
    except ActuallyResponsePacket:
        pkt = SKBusResponsePacket(raw_pkt.data)
```

Comment: The approach looks weird. Why you can't create a factory function that'll just construct an object of required type?

Comment: @WGH I'm not opposed to that. I want to follow the best design principles, so I'll go read up on what are factory functions. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be best to separate the detection of the packet type from the instantiation process. If there were a function, `detect_type`, (which would be similar to the `getSkbPacketType` method) then

```
def make_packet(raw_pkt):
    packet_type = detect_type(raw_pkt.data)
    if packet_type == 'request':
        pkt = SKBusRequestPacket(raw_pkt.data)
    elif packet_type == 'response':
        pkt = SKBusResponsePacket(raw_pkt.data)
    return pkt
```

would be your cleanest option.

---

A less clean option would be to instantiate an SKBusPacket, inspect the `packet_type` attribute, and then instantiate the right kind of packet. Note there is no raising of exceptions:

```
class SKBusPacket(Packet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SKBusPacket, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.packet_type = self.getSkbPacketType()

def log_skbus(raw_pkt):
    pkt = SKBusPacket(raw_pkt.data)
    if pkt.packet_type == 'request':
        pkt = SKBusRequestPacket(raw_pkt.data)
    elif pkt.packet_type == 'response':
        pkt = SKBusResponsePacket(raw_pkt.data)
```

One problem with the above code is that `SKBusPacket.__init__` is called twice, once to determine the packet_type, and a second time while instantiating either a SKBusRequestPacket or SKBusResponsePacket. Maybe the calls are quick and this double instantiation process is not a major bottleneck. In that case, this workaround suffices.

If not, you could by-pass the normal instantiation process by changing the instance's class dynamically:

```
def make_packet(raw_pkt):
    pkt = SKBusPacket(raw_pkt.data)
    if pkt.packet_type == 'request':
        pkt.__class__ = SKBusRequestPacket
    elif pkt.packet_type == 'response':
        pkt.__class__ = SKBusResponsePacket
    return pkt
```

To do this, SKBusPacket must be a new-style class.
Note carefully that `SKBusRequestPacket.__init__` or `SKBusResponsePacket.__init__` would *not* get called if you change the class this way. It would give `pkt` access to the methods of those classes, but you would need to put any initialization code in the `make_packet` function itself.

Comment: I went for the first option. Thanks a lot for your help :)